# is this possible to convert from biblatex to bibtex format

Tags: bibliographies, formatting

My code are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=ynt,
 citestyle=numeric,
 bibstyle=numeric,
 maxnames=3,maxbibnames=99,
 sortcites,
 url=false,
 mincrossrefs=50
]{biblatex}

\bibliography{test}

\begin{document}

\cite{lustrec,eis07,DBLP:journals/corr/GarocheGK14,DBLP:conf/nfm/GarocheHKT14,Motzkin}

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Content of .bib file:

```
@electronic{lustrec,
    Author = {Garoche, {P}ierre-{L}o{\"\i}c and Xavier Thirioux and Kahsai, Temesghen},
    Date-Modified = {2016-07-03 06:50:42 +0000},
    Keywords = {software,own},
    Optnote = {collaboration avec l'IRIT et NASA Ames},
    Title = {LustreC: a modular Lustre compiler},
    Url = {https://github.com/coco-team/lustrec},
    Year = {2012--},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://github.com/coco-team/lustrec}}

@inbook{eis07,
    Author = {Beno\^{\i}t Combemale and Xavier Cr{\'{e}}gut and Garoche, {P}ierre-{L}o{\"\i}c and Xavier Thirioux and Fran\c{c}ois Vernadat},
    Bibsource = {DBLP, dblp.uni-trier.de},
    Crossref = {DBLP:conf/iceis/2007sp},
    Date-Modified = {2016-07-03 06:50:42 +0000},
    Doi = {10.1007/978-3-540-88710-2_23},
    Keywords = {own},
    Pages = {286-300},
    Title = {A Property-Driven Approach to Formal Verification of Process Models},
    Year = {2007},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-88710-2_23}}

@inproceedings{DBLP:journals/corr/GarocheGK14,
    Author = {Garoche, {P}ierre-{L}o{\"\i}c and Arie Gurfinkel and Temesghen Kahsai},
    Bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, dblp.org},
    Biburl = {dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bib/journals/corr/GarocheGK14},
    Booktitle = {Proceedings of the First Workshop on Horn Clauses for Verification and Synthesis, {HCVS} 2014, Vienna, Austria, 17 July 2014.},
    Crossref = {DBLP:journals/corr/BjornerFRS14},
    Date-Modified = {2016-07-03 06:50:42 +0000},
    Doi = {10.4204/EPTCS.169.4},
    Keywords = {workshop,own},
    Pages = {19--30},
    Timestamp = {Mon, 05 Jan 2015 16:52:15 +0100},
    Title = {Synthesizing Modular Invariants for Synchronous Code},
    Year = {2014},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.4204/EPTCS.169.4}}

@inproceedings{DBLP:conf/nfm/GarocheHKT14,
    Author = {Garoche, {P}ierre-{L}o{\"\i}c and Falk Howar and Temesghen Kahsai and Xavier Thirioux},
    Bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, dblp.org},
    Biburl = {dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bib/conf/nfm/GarocheHKT14},
    Booktitle = {{NASA} Formal Methods - 6th International Symposium, {NFM} 2014, Houston, TX, USA, April 29 - May 1, 2014. Proceedings},
    Crossref = {DBLP:conf/nfm/2014},
    Date-Modified = {2016-07-03 06:50:42 +0000},
    Doi = {10.1007/978-3-319-06200-6_19},
    Keywords = {own},
    Metrics = {acceptance rate 35\%},
    Note = {Short paper},
    Pages = {246--251},
    Timestamp = {Fri, 25 Apr 2014 14:20:46 +0200},
    Title = {Testing-Based Compiler Validation for Synchronous Languages},
    Year = {2014},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-06200-6_19}}

@article{Motzkin,
    Author = {Th{\'e}odore Samuel Motzkin},
    Date-Modified = {2016-07-03 19:10:34 +0000},
    Journal = {Econometrica},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {184--185},
    Title = {Two consequences of the transposition theorem on linear inequalities},
    Volume = {19},
    Year = {1951}}
```

Output generated as:

[image]

Using `biblatex` everything working fine, my concern is is it possible to convert the same `from biblatex format to normal bibtex format`?

Comment: What do you mean by converting from biblatex format to normal bibtex format? With that `.bib` file it should be possible to just use `natbib` (say with `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`) instead of `biblatex`. Follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864 in reverse.

Comment: Aside: Please do not create tags that do not add anything new to this site. Instead, focus on choosing appropriate existing tags.

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot, currently I am in travel, will check and back to you...